# can I monitor contract events in python?

Tags: web3js, dapp-development, python

If I understand correctly, in web3.js the [allevents](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-allevents) method enables a contract event to be monitored.

is there an equivalent in python ?

Comment: Do you mean is there a Python based API similar to web3.js that can listen for events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do local testing of your contract, you can use PyEthereum's [tester](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/develop/ethereum/tester.py#L87) to capture and view events from your contract via the ABIContract class.

If you're looking for a Python based RPC client you may want to look at [ethjsonrpc](https://github.com/ConsenSys/ethjsonrpc). It appears ethjsonrpc has support for event functions.

Answer (score 2):

response to self but might be handy for others, there is a library called web3.py https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py that let you create filters (http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html)

you do it by creating a filter object, then you add a watch method to it that returns a callback function

```
def new_transaction_callback(transaction_hash):
    sys.stdout.write("New Block: {0}".format(transaction_hash))

new_transaction_filter = web3.eth.filter('pending')
new_transaction_filter.watch(new_transaction_filter)
```

Comment: `new_transaction_filter` does not have a method called `watch()` @euri10

Comment: If you are using Infura than this won't work. You have to set up your own node

Answer (score 0):

**2023**

- Using Ape you can fetch all of the event logs related to any event like this
- THis is an example of getting the `PairCreated` event of the `uniswap v2` router.

```py
from ape import project

address = "0xdead"

#contract = project.ContractName.at(address)
contract = project.IUniswapV2Factory.at(address)

for logs in contract.PairCreated:
    print(logs)
```

Comment: Here's a tutorial too if anyone finds it helpful https://chainstack.com/apeworx-ape-framework-what-is-it-and-how-to-use-it/